# How do I transform a distorted quadratic polynomial obtained from a 2D image of 3D space and obtain its formula?

Tags: arrays, math, transform, polynomials, non-linear-regression

Given an array of points representing a quadratic polynomial but that is warped/distorted due to the 3D perspective of the image (see figure 1). The first index of the array contains (x,y) pixel coordinate of the left intersection with the x-axis, the last index of the array contains the (x,y) pixel coordinate of the right intersection with the x-axis.

[image: figure 1]

How can I transform each pixel coordinate of the array into a formula for the quadratic polynomial as depicted in figure 2? Is this even possible?

[image: figure 2]

I have tried to use the cross-ratio as it does contain a vanishing point, but was unable to see if and how that would be helpful in this case. I also think the polynomial regression theory can be of use in some way.

Comment: The graph of the polynomial exists in some 2D plane, so I suppose you want to recover both the equation of the plane and that of the quadratic polynomial in the plane solely from the pixels and the information that the curve is a quadratic. I don't really know if there is a unique solution.

Comment: I would guess this could also be asked on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com), but here is a relevant question already asked and answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578680/projection-of-a-curve-on-a-plane

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious here, but if you know the curve is quadratic and in the x,y plane, then if you know where it intersects with the x and y axes, its trivial to calculate a,b, and c. The projection method will affect the 3D image's view of how far these intersection points appear from the origin. With Parallel Projection, you could probably do some elementary trig to come up with these intersection points' x,y coordinates.

Comment: @SimonGoater I have drawn the x and y axis by hand and don't know the exact intersection between those axis as I don't know how to derive the highest point of the distorted parabola. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: You should include the values of the array you have in your question. You don't need the highest point to get c, only where it intersects with the y axis, meaning y = c @x=0. if you know x_1 and x_2 where the curve intersects the x axis @y=0, then a(x_1 + x_2) + b = 0 and (x_1 - x_2)^2 = (b^2 - 4ac)/a^2.